# Vue JS - How to create dynamic input fields with models based on variable data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, templating, v-model

I have a Vue component, that creates a number of inputs based on the data fetched by the API. I run the values from the JSON through a method, that in turn converts this value to an input field if a certain condition matches. Here's how my component looks:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="(val, index) in data">
            <span>{{val.key}}</span>
            <span :inner-html.prop="checkForEdit(val)"></span>
        </div>
        <b-button @click="submitData">Save</b-button>
    <div>
</template>

export default {
    name: "SomeComp",
    data() {
        return {
            dynamicVars: {}
        }
    },
    methods: {
        ...mapActions("api", ["getData"]),
        checkForEdit(value) {
            if(!value) return '';
            if(value.mustEdit) {
                this.dynamicVars[value.key] = '';
                return '<input type="text" value= "'+ value.text +'" :model='+ this.dynamicVars[value.key]+'>';
            } else {
                return value.text;
            }
        },
        submitData() {
            console.log(this.dynamicVars); //Only the key is present, no value updated
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.getData();
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapState("api", ["data"]),
    }
};
```

Here's how the data looks:

```
[
    {key: 'name', text: 'John', mustEdit: false},
    {key: 'age', text: '100', mustEdit: true}
]
```

This data can be anything, the fields are not fixed, only the format is. So I want to create dynamic vars object on the fly to send to the API that saves it.

Right now it only creates the variable inside `dynamicVars` however it doesn't seem that it actually reacts when I change the field value.

Answer (score 2):

`innerHTML` has no clue about Vue templates, bindings and reactivity - if you set `domNode.innerHTML = '<input v-model="variable">';` the browser will simply ignore the attribute `v-model` as it is not a standard HTML5 attribute.

You need to switch your mental model and instead of thinking in imperative terms try to think declaratively - just write in your template what you want to do and Vue will do the magic for you. It is such a blessing that we have Vue to do things for us instead of writing code in the old jQuery-style.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="(val, index) in data" :key="index">
            <label :for="'input_' + index">{{val.key}}</label>
            <input v-if="val.mustEdit" :id="'input_' + index" :model='val.text'>
            <span v-else>{{ val.text }}</span>
        </div>
        <b-button @click="submitData">Save</b-button>
    <div>
</template>

export default {
    name: "SomeComp",
    methods: {
        ...mapActions("api", ["getData"]),
        submitData() {
            console.log(this.data);
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.getData();
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapState("api", ["data"]),
    }
};
```

Comment: Aha, I never thought in this way. Let me try this! Btw I ended up using `Vue.set` to no avail.

Comment: But, I have to create a separate object with the edited fields, API constraints. How would I do it then? I am trying your solution as we speak.

Comment: You can clone your original object and when you are ready to save the changes - you will iterate your cloned object key by key and compare its `text` value with the corresponding value in the original object and thus you will find which fields have been actually edited and then send to API only those. Or you can handle the `@input` event of the INPUT and mark the value as dirty - `@input="val.modified = true"` and then you will send to API `data.filter(obj => obj.modified)` elements